# Do i need IOS developer account for React native ios developing

Tags: ios, react-native

im going to port my app to IOS. i already built it on android but needs some package linking and some refactor for ios version. but im not going to deploy it on App Store. im going to upload my outputs(both android and ios) on a website to download.

in android you can easily create an apk and give it to anyone to test it for you.

i didn't have mac - iphone to test my app until now. having that in mind i have few questions:

1- do i have to have Apple Developer ID to be able to test my app even in debug mode?

2- if 1's answer is no, does creating IOS output require `Apple Developer ID` even if i dont want to push it to App Store

3- is it possible to install apps on IOS, downloading the output file(.ipa) from a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- do i have to have Apple Developer ID to be able to test my app even in debug mode?
You need to have a developer account. But simply to run the application you don't need to purchase any plan. They allow 2-3 free device debugging.

2- if 1's answer is no, does creating IOS output require Apple Developer ID even if i dont want to push it to App Store
For simply running the application you would not need but to enable services like push notifications or sharing the build you would definitely need.

3- is it possible to install apps on IOS, downloading the output file(.ipa) from a website?
Yes it is possible but you need to register your application with a developer account with a plan. And distribute the application with Production certificates.

Comment: And for 3 you also need to include in the app bundle provisioning profile the UDID of all devices you want to install the app on (limited to 100 devices)

Comment: Also, without Mac, you can't develop applications for iOS